# Spring AOP - Custom Annotation not coming through in JoinPoint

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am trying to use Spring AOP to capture some logging data on my controller classes.

I am using a custom annotation for this purpose but it seems to be failing.

```
@Around("execution(* path.to.package.endpoints.*Controller.*(..))")
private Object controllerMethodTimer(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)joinPoint.getSignature();
    Annotation[][] annotations = signature.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
    String[] parameterNames = signature.getParameterNames();
    Object[] parameterValues = joinPoint.getArgs();
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations[i]) {
                if (Loggable.class.isInstance(annotation)) {
                    Loggable loggable = (Loggable) annotation;
                if (loggable.name() !=  ""){
                    parameters.put(loggable.name(), parameterValues[i].toString());
                } else {
                    parameters.put(parameterNames[i], parameterValues[i].toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
//do stuff
//when printing the parameters map, it is always blank
}
```

Loggable class:

```
public @interface Loggable {

String name() default "";
}
```

The Method In Question:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> defaultLens(RestContext restContext,
                                                @Loggable @RequestBody LensRequest parameters,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "plugins", required = false) String commaDelimitedPluginNames) {
//some stuff
}
```

I've tried swapping the positions of Loggable/RequestBody in the above snippet.

What I am finding is that a log.info in the Aspect class's loops will show that RequestBody is being found and placed in the annotation array, but Loggable is not.

A previous iteration of the code which used:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
        Loggable annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(parameterValues[i].getClass(), Loggable.class);
        if (annotation != null){
            if (annotation.name() !=  ""){
                parameters.put(annotation.name(), parameterValues[i].toString());
            } else {
                parameters.put(parameterNames[i], parameterValues[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Found that Loggable was always null and the != null part of the loop was never being hit.

**Resolution:**

Per comment below, Custom Annotation needs `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

New Loggable class looks like this:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {

    String name() default "";
}
```

This is working.

Comment: You should probably include the `@Retention(value=RUNTIME)` annotation on your annotation class.

Comment: Thank you @AlessandroPower. This was the issue with Loggable.